# Unicode characters is shuffled in php imagettftext

Tags: php, unicode

I am trying to print unicode characters in image using GD library

I have following code

```
    $text = "கைவிடப்பட்ட";
    $font = "arial.ttf";
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(2500, 500);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 2500, 500, $white);
    imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
```

Original text here is கைவிடப்பட்ட , but it prints as following , you can see that first letter is replaced.

[image: demo]

Edit : I have tried 5 different fonts All results in same(online font preview is showing characters correctly) .  whereas when I echo the string via php(from database) to browser, output is exactly same(கைவிடப்பட்ட), but why imagettftext is switching characters..

Comment: Is (1) your HTML/Browser view UTF-8, (2) your file enconding UTF-8? And please clarify what "GD library" is.

Comment: I guess GD library is php-gd extension.

Comment: Using the right font? Try another font that may not have a different interpretation of whatever that first character is.

Comment: 1. You're using a `$font` variable that isn't shown to be declared and 2) not all fonts support all character sets, so ...

Comment: Why did I get lots of -1 ? can some one explain ?

Comment: @Randall : I used 5 different fonts , all results in same , In tamil language first two character you see is single  character , but its getting switched

Comment: I dont know why all the downvotes. It seems a legit question, with a legit problem that you ran into and were unable to figure out.

Comment: OffTopic: Have you looked into (or have available on your server) the Imagick set? Its far more robust than gd, and may solve your troubles if gd refuses to behave.

Comment: I tried imagick too $image->annotateImage($draw, 11, 11, 0, $text); and few more fonts , still its switching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about GD library and environment but I guess the issue is due to rendering. கை = combination of க + ை and the environment doesn't support the rendering for unicode while displaying. so either check any rendering solution or use non unicode fonts or do below workaround to tackle it in php.

```
$text = "கைவிடப்பட்ட";
$imgtext = tamilrender($text);
$font = "arial.ttf";
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(2500, 500);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 2500, 500, $white);
imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $imgtext);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

function tamilrender($input)
{$input=  preg_replace("/([க-ஹ])([ைேெ])/u", "$2$1", $input);
$input= preg_replace("/([க-ஹ])ொ/u", "ெ$1ா", $input);
$input= preg_replace("/([க-ஹ])ோ/u", "ே$1ா", $input);
return $input;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Limitations of Unicode

The Unicode standard policy is to encode only characters, not glyphs. `கை`, includes a combination character onto `க`.  of Tamil is treated a complex script that requires complex processing, and many software components don't properly handle it.

The best approach would be to find, or create, a php extension library which was written specifically for Tamil.

Comment: Its already UTF-8 , when used with mb_detect_encoding ... imagetftext is switching the characters ,, but if I echo the string directly from database via php to browser , its working properly